# How to make json response Unified format in spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want all json response is

```
{
   "status":"ok"
    "data":"..."
}
```

I only care @ResponseBody function return value;Don't need wrap any object to do it;

example:

```
@ResponseBody
public String test(){
   return "Hello,World"
}
```

I want get

```
{
   "status":"ok"
    "data":"Hello,World"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`ResponseBodyAdvice`can do it.you can implement the interface to handle ReqeustBody. Here is the [api](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseBodyAdvice.html).
In the documents.

> Allows customizing the response after the execution of an @ResponseBody or a ResponseEntity controller method but before the body is written with an HttpMessageConverter.
>   Implementations may be registered directly with RequestMappingHandlerAdapter and ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver or more likely annotated with @ControllerAdvice in which case they will be auto-detected by both.

here is a simple code.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public customerResponseBody implements ResponseBodyAdvice{
    @Override
    public boolean supports (MethodParameter returnType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType){
        return true;
    }

    @Override  
    public Object beforeBodyWrite (Object body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response){
        body = new ResponseTemplate<Object>("001",body);
        return body;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must return a Object instead of String for example :

```
public class CustomResponse {
  private String status;
  private String data;

  // Getters & Setters
}

@ResponseBody
public CustomResponse test(){
    CustomResponse response = new CustomResponse();

    response.setStatus("OK");
    response.setData("Hello,World");

    return response;
}
```

Comment: don't need wrap any object,I want transparent

Answer (score 0):

I thought it is not a good solution but you can format string

```
@RequestMapping(value="testData")
public @ResponseBody String testData(){
    String sdata="ok";
    String value ="Hello,World";

    return "{\"status\" :\""+sdata+"\",\"data \":\""+value+"\"}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solve problem.
rewrite default RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor can wrap any object to return value